# jquery calculate the sum of products x Quantity

Tags: jquery

I use this code to calculate the sum : http://jsfiddle.net/QmTNZ/2/

I want to modify it, to show 0 when there is no valid quantity or it is empty and not "NaN"

I want also to format the Sum to have only 2 numbers after the comma.

Help (I'm beginner in jquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `isNaN` function to check whether a number is actually a number or not:

```
if(isNaN(sum)) {
    //Show 0
}
else {
    //Show the value
}
```

To round the sum to 2 decimal places, you could do something like this:

```
Math.round(sum * 100) / 100;
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QmTNZ/20/) showing how it could work.

Comment: Thanks James Allardice, how can I concatenate the sign € in the end of the Sum tds ??

Comment: Just concatenate it like you usually would. JavaScript automatically converts the number to a string: `.text((Math.round(sum * 100) / 100) + "€");`

Comment: "€" appear as a strange sign like this : �
How can I use html encode in place of using "€"
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Change `.text(...)` to `.html(...)` and use `&euro;` instead of the character itself. That should solve it.

Comment: Super ! I have unfortunately found another little bug, with prices like : 10.000,00 ; in the sum for example of 10.000,00 x 2 I get 20 and not 20.000

Comment: That's because you're using a `.` in the number, which is treated as a decimal point, so `10.000 x 2 = 10 x 2 = 20`. Just omit the `.` and it will work fine.

Comment: @JamesAllardice let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1357/discussion-between-bizboss-and-james-allardice)

Answer (score 3):

Inside your loop, you can check for NaN and replace it with zero:

```
 if(isNaN(sum)) sum = 0;
```

For rounding, use this function:

```
function roundNumber(num, dec) {
    var result = Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,dec))/Math.pow(10,dec);
    return result;
}
```

ie,

```
sum = sum.roundNumber(sum, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

***demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gN3Te/***

```
$("tr.sum").each(function() {

    var $qnt = $(this).find(".qty");
    var $price = $(this).find("td").eq(1);

    console.log($qnt + " | " + $price);

    var q = $qnt.val();
    if (isNaN($qnt.val()) || $qnt.val() == '') q = 0;

    var sum = parseFloat($price.text()) * parseFloat(q);

    $(this).find("td").eq(2).text(sum.toFixed(2));

    $overall += sum;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

To format the sum to have two numbers change this:

```
$(this).find("td").eq(2).text(sum);
```

to:

```
$(this).find("td").eq(2).text(sum.toFixed(2));
```

Then add this

```
if(isNaN($qnt.val()) || $qnt.val() == "")
            $qnt.val(0);
```

That will set the quantity to zero if no value exists